# Giving managed control handles to unmanaged code - Access Violation

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, access-violation

So I have this SDK provided by a third party which is used for viewing streaming video from a remote source. The remote source runs a server provided by the third party that captures and stores video, and I can connect to that server and get video via the SDK. I am referencing the SDK via COM, and basic nongraphical operations like connecting to the server, selecting a video feed etc are all working just fine.

The problem is that the main (only) method for actually showing video to the user using this SDK is to pass an hWnd (as an int) into a method that will then asynchronously paint the video onto the client area of that window. "Window" here, to my knowledge, has the meaning of a GUI window, which in .NET terms would be any WinForms control with a window handle. In my case, I'm using PictureBox controls (one per feed the user wishes to see).

The problem is that I apparently cannot just drop a managed PictureBox control's handle into this SDK method, because when I do so I receive an AccessViolationException from the unmanaged thread. I'm working off of an example program written in VB 6 (which works on my computer against a test server) which does the same thing with a VB PictureBox, and that works just fine, but apparently whatever the SDK is trying to do to our nice safe .NET sandbox objects is not flying with the CLR.

Help? I wish I could give more information or a code sample, but I can't provide anything sanitized enough that it would work in the general case and I can't divulge the SDK being used. I think that what I need is simply to tell .NET that my referenced code should be trusted to do what it wants with the window, OR to somehow move the window to an less-managed memory space outside my program's comfy sandbox.

**EDIT:** OK, a little progress has been made. I am now verifying that the handle for the control has been created using IsHandleCreated, before giving the handle to the method. However, as Hans Passant said, an IntPtr is not an int. So, how do I fit this square peg in the round hole? I have tried both the ToInt32() function and an explicit cast to (int). Neither works, even when compiling my library for 32-bit architecture. Do I go back to the third party and say their SDK is a POS for not letting me pass a pointer?

Comment: Should work.  A hWnd is not an int, don't try to make this work on a 64-bit operating system.  There are otherwise plenty of ways for native code to bomb with an AV without your help.

Comment: You know what? That just might be it; I'm developing in Win7 64-bit, and the interop requires an int, to which I cannot pass the IntPtr Control.Handle directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine.  A `Control.Handle` for a windows forms control is just a standard HWND from the Windows API.  Many DirectX samples use this exact technique.

That being said, make sure this isn't passed into the native code until after the control is created.  If you pass the handle during a form's constructor (prior to Load), for example, the Handle will be invalid at that point.

Comment: Thanks. The entire UserControl containing the PictureBoxes in question will attempt to set up the initial set of video feeds in its Load event. Is this too soon?

Comment: This is the problem; the control's IsHandleCreated property is false, so I can't depend on the handle's value at this time. I've added a check that will skip the call, but now video never shows because there's apparently never a handle. More help?

Comment: @KeithS: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handlecreated.aspx  It may help :)

Comment: Thanks. I found that though the PBs were visible, they were on a panel that wasn't. Making sure that panel was visible got me valid handles. However, I'm still getting the AccessViolationException, possibly related to casting the window handle. See edit

Comment: @KeithS: You could (maybe) check the value of hte window handle pointer before/after `ToInt32()`, just to verify that is the problem... That being said, passing an HWND as int is just bad, in every way :(

Comment: I have verified that the number is the same before and after the casts. So is the major problem overflow, or something deeper and more sinister?

Comment: @KeithS: It very likely may be something else, then (though that's still bad)

Comment: I never found the exact problem, but the "meta-problem" was that I was attempting to create my implementation by "cloning" an existing implementation of the basic video plug-in interface that used a different API with different features. I went back to the drawing board and reimplemented my plug-in from scratch without inheriting any cruft, and it worked in the main viewer program first try. Since this is the sole answer given, and says that it should have worked just fine (which it did after getting rid of the cruft), you get the tick.